# How to interpolate a React Component using coffeescript?

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript

I want to call the component **Icon** in the component **Title** but all the ways I tried throws syntax error or just print like a plain text: **< Icon />**

My code:

```
{div, h2} = React.DOM
@Title  = React.createClass
  render: ->
      div {className: "title page"}, [(h2 {className: 'h2header ui header block'}, '<Icon />')])


@Icon = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<i className="icon user"></i>`
```

I'm based on this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
@Title  = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'title page'
      React.DOM.h2
        className: h2header ui header block
      React.createElement Icon
```

Comment: Super! Thank you. Works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

To get more readable code, I create class factories instead of React classes, using this utility function:

```
classFactory: (spec) ->
  c = React.createClass(spec)
  return (attrs, children...) ->
    React.createElement(c, attrs, children)
```

Then define your components like this:

```
Title = classFactory
  render: ->
    div className: "title page",
      h2 className: "h2header ui header block",
        Icon {}

Icon = classFactory
  render: ->
    i className: "icon user"
```

Comment: It looks nice, can you explain me a little bit about the classFactory? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `Icon` being a React class (that you need to pass to React.createElement), `classFactory` returns a function that creates the class for you. You just pass in the attributes and child nodes. It ends up doing the same thing, it just looks a little cleaner.